# Extract PDF Data using categorized annotations

Tags: pdf, csv, extract, ocr, annotations

Are there any existing tools to extract data from PDF files using this method.
Lets say I have 3 categories

1. **Image** - this will be a rectangle annotation which will crop that specific area where the annotation is placed
2. **Title** - this is another rectangle annotation will just get the text within that rectangle. If image, it will be converted to text through OCR
3. **Author** - same with #2 , but now mapped to author

Then will produce a file format , let's say a CSV:

```
ImageURL,Title,Author
```

This categories (fields) should be also grouped to records so it will have 1 record per row.

If there is no existing tool to do this what tools or programming API/SDK could help me build one?